# Can someone explain the following code for me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm trying to understand Promise. But here I'm confused.
I want to create a test function that will print 3000 after 3 second, then print 2000 after 2 second, then print 1000 after 1 second. Here is my code:

```
'use strict';
var Q = require('q');

function delayConsole(timeOut) {
    var defer = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(timeOut);
        defer.resolve(2000);
    },timeOut);
    return defer.promise;
}

// This works
delayConsole(3000).then(function(){
    return delayConsole(2000);
}).then(function(){
    return delayConsole(1000);
    });

// This doesn't work. Why?
delayConsole(3000).then(delayConsole(2000)).then(delayConsole(1000));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There, you call the function `delayConsole` immediately :

```
.then(delayConsole(2000))
```

That is : you don't pass the function but the result of the function call, you don't wait for the promises to be chained.

When you do

```
then(function(){
    return delayConsole(2000);
})
```

then you pass a function, not the result of that function call. The function can be called when the previous element in the promise chain is solved.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that Q ships with a `.delay` function.

Comment: This explains a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I'd share that you can make this construction work which is sometimes easier to use:

```
promise.then(delayConsole(3000)).then(delayConsole(2000)).then(delayConsole(1000));
```

by changing `delayConsole()` to this:

```
function delayConsole(timeOut) {
    return function() {
        var defer = Q.defer();
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(timeOut);
            defer.resolve(2000);
        },timeOut);
        return defer.promise;
    }
}
```

This way, calling `delayConsole()` just captures the timeout argument and returns a function that can be called later by the promise `.then` handler.  So, you are still passing a function reference to the `.then()` handler which lets the promise engine call the internal function sometime later rather than execute it now.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00. You guys are great!